# Electron: Minimize the application when launched after computer is restarted

Tags: electron

I am using [node-auto-launch](https://github.com/Teamwork/node-auto-launch) to launch my application after computer is restarted. This application is only for windows. I want this application by default to be launched minimized as it works in the background. HOw can I achieve this?

```
let bizAnalystAutoLauncher = new AutoLaunch({
  name: 'BizAnalystDesktop'
});

bizAnalystAutoLauncher.enable();
bizAnalystAutoLauncher.isEnabled()
  .then(function (isEnabled: boolean) {
    if (isEnabled) {
      return;
    }
  bizAnalystAutoLauncher.enable();
})
.catch(function (err: any) {
// handle error
 console.log(err);
});
```

I don't want the application to be hidden. The application icon should be visible in the system tray in the taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to have some kind of "minimize to tray" behaviour.

Initialize your app the usual way but instead of `mainWindow.show()` you call `mainWindow.minimize()` after initializing the mainWindow, then add EventListeners for the mainWiondw's `minimize` and `restore` events to hide or show the taskbar icon for your app via `mainWindow.setSkipTaskbar()`:

```js
...
mainWindow.on('restore', () => {
    mainWindow.setSkipTaskbar(false)
})

mainWindow.on('minimize', () => {
    mainWindow.setSkipTaskbar(true)
})
...
```

Add a Tray menu like in the [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md) but make sure you add a menu item to restore the app window, otherwise you will end up with an app that is not accessible after it is minimized:

```js
...
const trayMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        label: 'Show',
        click: () => {
            mainWindow.restore()
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Quit',
        role: 'quit'
    }
])
tray.setContextMenu(trayMenu)
...
```

Comment: if anyone is bothered by the icon on the dock of the mac you can use this line of code to hide it. But remember to add a quit option on the tray:
app.dock.hide();

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is I would create a shortcut in the start menu `Programs > startup` with an argument instead of using `node-auto-launch`. Then when the app runs check for that argument in `process.argv`.

So to create a start menu shortcut with an argument of `startMinimized` you can use this module called [`windows-shortcuts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-shortcuts)

```
require('windows-shortcuts').create(
    '%APPDATA%/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/myApp.lnk', {
        target: process.execPath,
        args:   'startMinimized',
        icon:   'path/to/icon'
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw Error(err);
        }
    }
);
```

Then you could write some script like this to minimize the window at startup:

```
var startMinimized = false;
if (process.argv[2] && process.argv[2].indexOf('startMinimized') != -1) {
    startMinimized = true;
}

var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({show: !startMinimized});
if (startMinimized) {
    mainWindow.minimize();
}
```

`process.argv` is an array of arguments the app starts with. The first one is the `.exe` path. The second is the squirrel argument.