# How to open an electron app without opening a window

Tags: javascript, electron

im making a clipboard application in Electron. So far ive made it so you can open the program and it will go in your tray but a window opens as well and is not needed for my program to run properly. 
Here is my code. Ive been scratching my head trying to figure out how to have it run the program without opening a window.

TIA

Code:

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, Tray, Menu} = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow



function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true

    }
  })

  const ret = globalShortcut.register("Super+Alt+V", () => {
     mainWindow.isVisible()
      ? mainWindow.hide()
      : mainWindow.show();
    });


    if(!ret) {
      console.error('failed to register hotkey');
    }


    tray = new Tray('./Nstar2.jpg');
    tray.setToolTip('Racesim');

    tray.displayBalloon({
      title: "Hey",
      content: "It looks like you copied something..."
    });

    const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {label: 'Exit', type: 'normal', click:() => {
      app.quit();
    }},

    ])

    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})



app.on('activate', function () {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Basically i want it to open and stay in the tray and thats all.

Comment: Might wanna take a look at [maxogden/menubar](https://github.com/maxogden/menubar) for clue

Comment: It just makes a browser window https://github.com/maxogden/menubar/blob/23f43c55b4c02b83cd03cc6c129e50fb3de53f83/src/Menubar.ts#L287-L290

Answer (score 2):

In short, Electron doesn't let you start the application without showing a window. Your only option would be to minimize the window as soon as the application launches.

Most people seem to rely on the [auto-launch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch) package (or similar) to achieve this. This package just allows you to pass and parse an argument to your node app.

Here's some helpful resources, I recommend you check them out:

- [how to auto run electron app as minimized (on tray) when windows start](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6893)
- [Electron: Minimize the application when launched after computer is restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014473/electron-minimize-the-application-when-launched-after-computer-is-restarted)
- [Let’s build a system tray cryptocurrency tracker for Mac using Electron](https://medium.com/@nahoc/lets-build-a-system-tray-cryptocurrency-tracker-for-mac-using-electron-part-1-7888747891b)

Comment: What's the mechanism for this? In your main entry point you are running code in a Node process with no browser window showing, then you decide when to open the first BrowserWindow. Does it kill the process if you haven't opened a BrowserWindow after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

win = new BrowserWindow({show: false});

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm crazy here but I think the answer is just to not create a BrowserWindow. You can manage your app from the [Tray API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/tray), which can be called from the Main process.

I created a small proof of concept app and it seems to work just fine.